# How to display contents of another HTML file on server within a zend .phtml view?

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, view

I have a zend application that generates and stores a `.html` file on the server in the public folder. It is a caching mechanism and is run once a day on a cron job.

I would like the zend view `cache.phtml` to contain the contents of the most newly generated `.html` file. How can I do that.

Lets say the `'html` file generated is called `report.html`.

Thanks

Comment: Have posted an answer using the Zend_Cache component. Not sure if you're using ZF1 or ZF2 though.

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Zend 1.12

Comment: My instructions will work as is for Zend 1.12 (I use 1.12 myself and it's based very closely on my live code). If you're looking for *the* Zend way to do it, that's probably it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a [`view helper`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html) to get the contents of the cache. The view helper would contain a simple PHP method to locate the correct file, read its contents, and return it:

```
class App_View_Helper_Cache extends
    extends Zend_View_Helper_Abstract
{
    public function cache()
    {
        $file = <however you figure out what the file is>;
        return file_get_contents($file);
    }
}
```

Then, in your view, you'd simply echo the view helper:

```
<?= $this->cache() ?>
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, in the mean time I just used a `include($cachefile);` in `cache.phtml` but your solution is the best practice when using zend

Answer (score 0):

**To render a flat HTML file in place:**

You don't need to create a helper for this, you *could* just use:

```
<?= $this->render('/path/to/report.html') ?>
```

**But don't use that, use Zend_Cache:**

However, you should look into [Zend_Cache](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.cache.html), you may find that it's more consistent with the rest of your application to load variables from the Zend Cache in your Model instead of pulling from the database.

*Note: These instructions are for Zend Framework 1, Zend Framework 2 cache [has similar capabilities](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/index.html#zend-cache) but is not the same.*

First, create the cache:

```
$frontendOptions = array(
   'lifetime' => 60*60*24, // cache lifetime of 24 hours
   'automatic_serialization' => true
);
$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => './tmp/' // Directory where to put the cache files
);

$cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Core','File',$frontendOptions,$backendOptions);
```

Then do this to get the values when you want them:

```
public function cacheAction(){
    ...
    if(!$result = $cache->load('daily_report')){
        $result = dailyFunction();
        $cache->save($result, 'daily_report')
    }
    $this->view->result = $result;
}
```

This will run `dailyFunction()` once a day (as defined in `lifetime` variable) and return the `$result` from cache or from the function. Then you can use it in your view as normal.

No cron jobs, no static HTML files, and all the advantages of caching.

Comment: The file takes about 16 minutes to generate on the server, so I don't want the user to ever have to generate it. Does this solution do that. I know `cacheAction()` would go in controller but where would the `$frontendoptions` be declared and should `dailyFunction` be in the controller?

Comment: Oh OK, in that case you would have to do this with a cron: `$result = dailyFunction(); $cache->save($result, 'daily_report');`

Comment: We instantiate the `Zend_Cache` object in `Application.php` as we use it in a lot of places throughout the site. `dailyFunction()` can be anywhere as long as you call it correctly. We have a bunch of functions in our models which are cached when run.